# Laravel 5.6 & AJAX: jQuery.load()のurlパラメターとして、{{ }}表現を使うのは本当に可能？

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

下記の例（[情報源](https://atuweb.net/201609_laravel-get-ajax-request/)）を見た時に、`jQuery.ajax`の`url`パラメターとしてbladeテンプレートと同じように`{{ }}`表現を使っても良いと推測しました。

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "{{ url('/api/login') }}",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    user   : user,
    passwd : passwd
  })
  :
});
```

Laravelは`{{ url() }}`というAJAX要求を理解しているなら、`{{ route() }}`も理解してくれると推測し、次のAJAX要求を制作してみました。

```
changeFragment(newFragment){

    let fragmentUrn = '{{ route( "admin.GetFragmentViaAjax", ["fragment" => "requests_all"]) }}';

    this.$MainContent.load(fragmentUrn, (response, status, xhr) => {
        status === 'success' ?  resolve() : reject(xhr);
    });
}
```

そのようにしてみますと、このようなエラーが出ます：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

問題は完全にJavaScriptの側にあるようです。

Comment: `%7B%7B` は `{{` なんですがこのコードはどこに書かれたものですか？ Blade内？

Comment: Chromeのコンソルです。スクリーンショットに追加しております。

Comment: あ、そうではなくてJSコードをどこに書いたかです

Comment: jsファイルの中に書きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade内に書かれたコードはPHPにコンパイルされ、サーバー側で実行されてブラウザに返されます。そのため、質問で例として上げられているものは

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "http://example.com/api/login",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
```

のように展開されるためJSは問題なくこれを実行できます。

> `{{ url() }}`という要求をしている

という認識がそもそもの誤りであり、実際にはJSはこの段階で上記のようにURLしか見えません。（HTTPリクエストでPHPのコードを渡しているわけではありません）

一方で外部のjsファイルにブラケット記法(`{{ }}`)でPHPのコードを書いたところでそのコードはPHPは通らず直接返されます。もちろんJSは素直に解釈することしか出来ませんから `http://example.com/{{` を読み込む、となります。

そもそももしクライアントからサーバーにPHPのコードが渡せるようであれば(そしてそれが実行されるのであれば)それは脆弱でしかありません。

Comment: ご回答に感謝します。なるほどですね、それBladeの中だったって、なかなか考えていませんでした。